# "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing" error when decoding JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting the following error :

The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

When I run the following code:

```
struct Indicator: Decodable {
    let section: String
    let key: Int
    let indicator: Int
    let threshold: Int
}
    var indicators = [Indicator]()

    do {
        if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "indicators", withExtension: "json") {
            indicators = try JSONDecoder().decode([Indicator].self, from: try Data(contentsOf: file))
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

These are in a function, but I have removed them for clarity. I have a code block which is very similar in a different file (I copied this code from there and changed the names essentially) so I'm not sure why it's happening. The json file is valid json and has it's target properly set.

Thanks

Comment: Show the beginning of the JSON. Put `Data(contentsOf` in an extra line and  `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: It looks exactly like the json file. [
     {
         "section": "A",
         "key": 0,
         "indicator": 4,
         "threshold": 0
     },
     {
        "section": "A",
        "key": 1,
        "indicator": 6,
        "threshold": 0
    }]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am dealing with exactly the same thing

Comment: Use debugPrint(error) in the catch block, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I just solved a similar issue on my end but for the property list decoder.

The error in this case seems to mean that a key wasn't found and not the data as a whole.

**Try making the variables in your struct optional** and it should return a nil value where the problem lies.

Comment: print(response.error as Any)
 
This will give you comprehensive information about the keys that are required to be handled as per this answer.

Comment: A better localised description would of saved us the headache. The current message is incorrect.

Answer (score 219):

Printing `error.localizedDescription` is misleading because it displays only a quite meaningless generic error message.

So **never use `localizedDescription` in `Decodable` catch blocks.**

In the simple form just

```
print(error)
```

It shows the full error including the crucial information `debugDescription` and `context`.`Decodable` errors are very comprehensive.

---

While developing code you could catch each `Decodable` error separately for example

```
} catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
    print(context)
} catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

It shows only the most significant information.

Comment: Holy! You just saved my azz. For 6 hours I wasn't getting any json data. No errors, no warnings nothing. My table simply wasn't loading with data. Then I removed `localizedDescription` and tried `error`. It told me where 3 mismatches were. It wasn't because of spelling it was because I had extra properties in the model that didn't exist in the json. Plus another Bool json issue. I cannot believe `localizedDescription` is so terrible. They should BAN this from Swift.  Thank you Vadian!!!!!!!!

Comment: @tymac `localizedDescription` is not bad per se and for simple errors it's pretty suitable and sufficient. On the other hand `DecodingError`s are more complex and the full description of the error is too large to fit into one *description* phrase.

Comment: I understand now. However I am traumatized and I will NEVER use localizedDescription in my life again. Never! ;(

Comment: This was the answer that helped me most.

Comment: Works. But printing an error without further description is not a great idea.

Comment: @brainray Do you mean the last error? Actually this `catch` block will never be reached in a standard implementation, it's added to silence a compiler warning.

Comment: @vadian I overlooked that, sorry!

Comment: I have been using `po error.localizedDescription` for years. Never knew that `po error` would provide more informative output.

Comment: that's very helpful, I hate that I have to have so many catch statements, but this was very helpful.

Comment: This is great. Simply `print(error)` allowed me to view the key that was causing issues. I could not see that because I was using `.. localizedDescription`. Nice.

Comment: Thank you very much, using ``localizedDescription`` was so useless. i spent days looking at meaningless error messages, using different types of code.

Comment: Use debugPrint(error) in the catch block, it'll work.

Comment: This is helpful, my data model has properties which is not optional, but API request returns nil for that property, which causes this problem. And `print(error)` gives me the clue where is wrong.

Answer (score 28):

**"The data couldn’t be read because it is missing"**

the error coming from this code:

```
...catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Because: seems that a key is missing or mistyped.

You can check **which key is missing** by coding like this:

```
...catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}
```

Note: If struct keys are different from JSON data keys, see below example:
the key in struct is 'title' but in data is 'name'.

```
struct Photo: Codable {
    var title: String
    var size: Size

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case title = "name"
        case size
    }
}
```

If you mistype 'name', the error will pop up.

Also, if you mistype this 'CodingKeys', you will get the error.

```
enum CodingKeys:...
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. Not really a great compiler message as usual...

Comment: This answer helped me solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Good to learn about `debugPrint`.

Comment: the debugPrint helped me so much, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Try printing the actual error instead of just the description. It should give you a message like `"No value associated with key someKey (\"actual_key_if_you_defined_your_own\")."`, which is much more useful than the `localizedDescription`.

Comment: Note that if you attempt to `po` in the console and it doesn't work, you may need an explicit `print` statement in code.

Answer (score 7):

The thing most people use but they should not is

```swift
print(error.localizedDescription)
```

As it is extremely misleading when it comes to JSON files. Instead, just use

```swift
print(error)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just had a same error. I had an error in manual code for decoder. In my code property **completedOn** was optional, but I was using **try** instead of **try?** when decoding it. When the value was missing in json, the decoding would fail for that property. See the code bellow to better understand what I mean.

```
public var uuid: UUID
public var completedOn: Date?

...

required public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.uuid = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .uuid)
    self.completedOn = try? container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .completedOn)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the properties optional then

If your case similar to this try this
**decodeIfPresent**

```
    `public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    firstName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    }`
```