# RealmSwift with Alamofire5

Tags: ios, swift, realm, alamofire, codable

I try to use RealmSwift with alamofire5 and Codable. I followed this guide to write a [network layer](https://medium.com/@AladinWay/write-a-networking-layer-in-swift-4-using-alamofire-5-and-codable-part-2-perform-request-and-b5c7ee2e012d).

Actually it works perfect, no problem until try to configure Realm.
I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452833/how-to-use-list-type-with-codable-realmswift) and find this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ansonyao/41137bb3cbbca8ef31a13b6bc96ee422). Unfortunately it did not solve my problem.

I also tried this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@swiftthesorrow/realm-codable-part-1-7629b9a1493a) but I got error, I guess alamofire5 decoder is complaning about something.(Error : `The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.`). I tried to solve the error with this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963493/4309963) but it did not work and I revert everything to realmless version.

Here is my struct:

```
struct User: Codable{
var account_type:Int? = -1
var gender:String? = ""
var age:Int? = 0
var password:String? = ""
var name:String? = ""
var email:String? = ""
var image_path:String? = ""
var access_token:String? = ""
var refresh_token:String? = ""
var device_id:String? = ""
var card_number:Int? = 0
var id_token:String? = ""
var status:Int? = STATUS_DESCRIPTION.BAD_REQUEST.rawValue
var msg: String? = ""

init(account_type:Int, device_id:String, token:String) {
    self.account_type = account_type
    self.device_id = device_id
    self.id_token = token
}
init(email:String, name:String, password:String, device_id:String, account_type:Int){
    self.password = password
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.account_type = account_type
    self.device_id = device_id
}
init(email:String, password: String, device_id:String, account_type:Int) {
    self.account_type = account_type
    self.device_id = device_id
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
}
}
```

Thanks for reading, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you should not assign values in front of each parameter and make them optional like this.
The model needs

```
init(){

}


init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{

}
```

write your model as described in this [link](https://medium.com/@sajjadsarkoobi/how-to-write-strong-models-for-swift-codable-and-reusing-that-model-again-41a8779eef6f)